# spacewalk on RHEL6

Tags: centos, rhel, spacewalk

is it possible to install Spacewalk on RHEL 6.9?
i only see community support on that.
and if it is not, is it possible that centos server can be the repository and from there on distributed to other types of Linux ? ( RHEL/ SUSE?)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. See https://github.com/spacewalkproject/spacewalk/wiki/HowToInstall

If you want commercial support then you can buy Red Hat Satellite 5 which is based on Spacewalk.

Mind that Red Hat Satellite 5 is being replaced by Red Hat Satellite 6, which is base on Foreman.

Comment: thanks i have seen it. what is foreman msuchy?

Comment: https://theforeman.org/